# eclipse "source attachment" vs "source lookup path"

Tags: java, eclipse

It seems to be that there are two different ways of attaching source jar to a java library in eclipse:

1. Right-click on jar file in `Referenced Libraries`, then click on `Properties > Java Source Attachment`.
2. Go to `Debug Configuration`, then click on `Source > Add... > Achieve`

But it appears that I need to do both for eclipse to behave properly. If I do step 1 only, then I can see the source code, but if I put a breakpoint in the source and start the debugger then it says source code missing. If I do step 2 only, then it shows the code while debugging but not if I press F3 in a library method.

Why does eclipse require that the source code path be specified twice? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know the real answer, but I think it may be related with [debug information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746894/what-does-the-javac-debugging-information-option-gvars-do)

Comment: For what library are you setting the `Java Source Attachment` that's getting forgotten, and how is it added to the `Java Build Path`?

Comment: @glueryuz, it has nothing to do with debug information. All debug information are already present in the compiled jar library because I can step into them line by line after attaching source.

Comment: @nitind, it's for jogl library but it doesn't matter because all libraries have same problem. I include the jar file in a lib folder in my project, then add them to Java Build path by right-clicking > Build Path > Add to Build Path...