# How do I figure out the identifier of an object in java?

Tags: java, object, identifier

I am writing some code and I am trying to use `System.out.println()` to print the name of an object.
For example, with the code `String foo = new String("Hi");`, I want to print out "`foo`".
How do I do this?

Comment: `System.out.println("foo");`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nice !

Comment: Yes, but that's hard-coded, which is not good

Comment: @WacfeldWang But it has the advantage that it will work.

Comment: I think you should read this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

Comment: @WacfeldWang You _cannot_ do this in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this, for multiple reasons. The simplest one is that one object can be referenced from multiple variables:

```
String foo = new String("Hi");
String bar = foo;
```

Now both `foo` and `bar` refer to the same `String` object `"Hi"`. There is no way to decide on a single identifier.

Names of local variables are, essentially, a compile-time artifact. Once the compiler is done, you cannot access these names without access to the debug information produced when you [compile with `-g:vars` compiler flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5746894/335858).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible the object reference name you give is not available at runtime.