# Debugging Java servlet with jdb. How to attach jdb with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jdb

I have a tomcat running after making configuration and when I type `jdb` in terminal it says initializing. So I like to know

1. How to attach jdb with tomcat and specify servlet name.
2. What is the compile option (like in C its eg. -g with gdb) to include debugging symbols when compiling servlet with `javac`

I have `opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.0.10` so I guess Tomcat version is 10

Comment: how to attach to -> `.class` <- file and tomcat to jdb believe its a binary file like `.o` in C C++

Answer (score 0):

The `javac` command switch to add all debugging symbols is ... `-g`. Line numbers and source file names are actually added by default, you only gain information on local variables (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5746894/11748454)).

You can not connect a debugger to a running JVM, unless it was started with the appropriate command line option (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138511/11748454)).

Tomcat has a helper script `bin/catalina.sh` that can help you start it with the correct parameters:

- `catalina.sh jpda start` starts Tomcat in the background with debugging enabled. You can connect to it with:

  ```
  jdb -attach localhost:8000
  ```
- `catalina.sh jpda run` works as in the previous case, but in the foreground,
- `catalina.sh debug` starts Tomcat through `jdb`. You just need to use `run` to start it.

Once you are connected you can use:

```
stop in <class id>.<method>
```

to add break points.

**Remark**: Both `javac` and `jdb` are not often used these days. Most people  use tools like Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc. to compile their projects and IDEs to debug the code.