# Why variable in .class files appear as var?

Tags: java

I was curious about .class files and the code inside and realised that variables in one of the classes that I compiled is named as ***var0*** which is very interesting.

I am wondering if someone could explain why.

Java Code (.java file):

```java
public class StackOverflowExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loop(50_000);
        System.out.println("Success!");
    }

    public static void loop(int repeats) {
        if (repeats > 0) {
            loop(repeats - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Decompiled Code (.class file):

```java
public class StackOverflowExample {
    public StackOverflowExample() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] var0) {
        loop(50000);
        System.out.println("Success!");
    }

    public static void loop(int var0) {
        if (var0 > 0) {
            loop(var0 - 1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it preserve the variable name?

Comment: Variable names are lost during compilation, they are not needed for the bytecode and hence dropped. The decompiler you used just guessed some names for you.

Comment: This question is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746894/what-does-the-javac-debugging-information-option-gvars-do

Comment: @shmosel – Because the decompiled code would look nicer? Ok, I could not imagine any other reason …

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the JVM level, a class method is stored as a [`method_info`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6) struct instance.

> ```
> method_info {
>     u2             access_flags;
>     u2             name_index;
>     u2             descriptor_index;
>     u2             attributes_count;
>     attribute_info attributes[attributes_count];
> }
> ```

- `access_flags` stores modifiers like `public` and `final` as bitflags.
- `name_index` stores the name of the method.
- `descriptor_index` stores the [method descriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.3), which is its return type and all parameter types.
- `attributes_count` and `attributes` are the runtime-available attributes such as `@Deprecated` that are declared on the method.

That's it. Everything else is gone. The `.class` file doesn't know the name of your function's parameter because that name stopped existing the moment it became a `.class` file. The decompiler is reconstructing your method, so it's using a placeholder name for variables that don't have names in the JVM instructions.

Comment: Note that the `attributes` *can* include attributes called `LocalVariableTable` which give information about the names of local variables. But that information is purely informational: it's useful for debugging, but not necessary for execution. Also the code of the method itself is actually [an attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3). So attributes are not just annotation-type information, but some fundamentally important parts of the method as well.